# Split content of field and duplicate row

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet which has one column which may have many values delimited by a semi-colon e.g value1;value2;value3.  What I need to do is to duplicate the entire row for each value, with each row having just one of the values.

Example:

```
value1;value2;value3,abc,100
value4;value5,xyz,200
value6,def,300
```

should end up like this:

```
value1,abc,100
value2,abc,100
value3,abc,100
value4,xyz,200
value5,xyz,200
value6,def,300
```

Comment: Look at VBA's [Split Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and variant arrays.

Comment: First split on `,` with a limit of `2`.  Then split the 0-th item in that array on `;` with no limit.  Iterate those results and join them back to the 1-th item from the first split.  You can then add rows if there is more than 1 item in that iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to split and write the data to different sheet...

Sheet 1 contains input and Sheet 2 contains the output as you requested...

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

i = 1  'Row
j = 1  'Col

'Destination Row & Col
x = 1
y = 1

While (Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value) <> "")
    Dim CellValue1 As String
    Dim CellValue2 As String
    Dim CellValue3 As String
    Dim ValArray() As String
    Dim arrayLength As Integer

    CellValue1 = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value)
    CellValue2 = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, (j + 1)).Value)
    CellValue3 = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, (j + 2)).Value)
    ValArray = Split(CellValue1, ";")
    arrayLength = UBound(ValArray, 1) - LBound(ValArray, 1) + 1

    k = 0
    While (k < arrayLength)
        'MsgBox ((ValArray(k) & CellValue2 & CellValue3))
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, y).Value = ValArray(k)
        y = y + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, y).Value = CellValue2
        y = y + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, y).Value = CellValue3
        x = x + 1
        y = 1
        k = k + 1
    Wend
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Answer (score 3):

With data in column **A** this macro:

```
Sub Byron()
    Dim r As Range, K As Long, v As String
    K = 1
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        p1 = Mid(v, 1, InStr(1, v, ",") - 1)
        p2 = Mid(v, InStr(1, v, ","))
        ary = Split(p1, ";")
        For Each a In ary
            Cells(K, 2).Value = a & p2
            K = K + 1
        Next a
    Next r
End Sub
```

will put the results in column **B**:

[image]

*(this is just a translation of Byron's comment into VBA)*